# R how to create counter and make it print to new column before every reset

Tags: r, counter

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
  df
R1 R2
0  0 
1  1
1  1
0  1
1  1 
0  0
0  1
1  0           
0  0
1  0
1  0
1  1
```

And I wish to create a counter that counts - in every column individually - the occurrences of '1's after another, reset after every encounter of a 0, and output the counts in a new column. i.e. in row 1 it would reset at first step, then count to 1, then count to 2, then reset, then count 1, then reset, reset, etc. with the desired output for column 1 being:

```
  df
R1(Counted) 
N/A   
N/A  
2  
N/A  
1   
N/A  
N/A  
1             
N/A  
N/A  
N/A  
3
```

I suspect I need something like:

```
Counter = 0  
for i = 1:nrow(df){
  if (???==1){
    counter=counter+1
  } else {
    counter=0
  }
}
```

But I really have no experience with counters and don't know how to make it continuously print its count to a new column before reseting the counter or anything like that.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a function taking help from `data.table::rleid` to create groups based on every change in value. Turn all the values to `NA` except the ones where the value is 1 and it is the last element in the group.

```
get_counter <- function(ct) {
   ave(ct, data.table::rleid(ct), FUN = function(x) 
           replace(seq_along(x), x != 1 | seq_along(x) != length(x), NA))
}
```

This funciton can be applied to multiple columns using `lapply`

```
df[paste0("ct_", names(df))] <- lapply(df, get_counter)
df

#   R1 R2 ct_R1 ct_R2
#1   0  0    NA    NA
#2   1  1    NA    NA
#3   1  1     2    NA
#4   0  1    NA    NA
#5   1  1     1     4
#6   0  0    NA    NA
#7   0  1    NA     1
#8   1  0     1    NA
#9   0  0    NA    NA
#10  1  0    NA    NA
#11  1  0    NA    NA
#12  1  1     3     1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(R1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), R2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```
a <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)

b <- sequence(rle(as.character(a))$lengths)
b[a == 0] <- NA                 
b[!is.na(dplyr::lead(b))] <- NA # this finds any where the next value isn't NA

b
# NA NA  2 NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  3
```

You could make this into a function and `lapply` over your data.frame to do every column all at once if you have more than 1 to do, like this:

```
counter <- function(x){

  count <- sequence(rle(as.character(x))$lengths)
  count[x == 0] <- NA
  count[!is.na(dplyr::lead(count))] <- NA

  return(count)
}

df <- data.frame(
  R1 = sample(c(0, 1), 20, T, c(0.2, 0.8)),
  R2 = sample(c(0, 1), 20, T, c(0.7, 0.3))
)

df[paste0(names(df), '_ct')] <- lapply(df, counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (rather convoluted) solution with just base `R` using a `while` loop each (for `R1` and `R2`)!!

```
df <- data.frame(R1 = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1), R2 = c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1))

#For R1
mycount <- 0
i <- 1
df$R1_counted <- NA
while(i <= nrow(df)){

  mycount <- mycount + df$R1[i]
  if(df$R1[i] == 0 & i == 1){
    df$R1_counted[i] <- NA
  } else if(df$R1[i] != 0 & i == 1){
    df$R1_counted[i] <- df$R1[i]
  }

  if(df$R1[i] == 0 & i > 1){
    df$R1_counted[i] <- NA
    if(df$R1[i-1] != 0){df$R1_counted[i-1] <- mycount}

    mycount <- 0
  } else if(df$R1[i] != 0 & i > 1){
    df$R1_counted[i] <- NA
  }

  if(i == nrow(df) & df$R1[i] != 0){
    df$R1_counted[i] <- mycount
  }

  i <- i + 1
}


#For R2
mycount <- 0
i <- 1
df$R2_counted <- NA
while(i <= nrow(df)){

  mycount <- mycount + df$R2[i]
  if(df$R2[i] == 0 & i == 1){
    df$R2_counted[i] <- NA
  } else if(df$R2[i] != 0 & i == 1){
    df$R2_counted[i] <- df$R2[i]
  }

  if(df$R2[i] == 0 & i > 1){
    df$R2_counted[i] <- NA
    if(df$R2[i-1] != 0){df$R2_counted[i-1] <- mycount}

    mycount <- 0
  } else if(df$R2[i] != 0 & i > 1){
    df$R2_counted[i] <- NA
  }

  if(i == nrow(df) & df$R2[i] != 0){
    df$R2_counted[i] <- mycount
  }

  i <- i + 1
}

df
#   R1 R2 R1_counted R2_counted
#1   0  0         NA         NA
#2   1  1         NA         NA
#3   1  1          2         NA
#4   0  1         NA         NA
#5   1  1          1          4
#6   0  0         NA         NA
#7   0  1         NA          1
#8   1  0          1         NA
#9   0  0         NA         NA
#10  1  0         NA         NA
#11  1  0         NA         NA
#12  1  1          3          1
```